# $G/H$ with $H$ contractible a fibre bundle?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Suppose $G$ is a topological group and $H\leq G$ a normal/closed subgroup of $G$.  If $H$ is contractible, does the quotient map $p: G\rightarrow G/H$ form a fibre bundle?

Is there a more general condition on $G$ or $H$ that guarantees that the map $p: G\rightarrow G/H$ is a fibre bundle? References for both of these questions will be warmly received

Comment: By *fiber bundle* you mean *locally trivial fiber bundle*?

Comment: @Mariano Yes I mean it is locally trivial. Could you provide me with an example of one that is not? I guess I always thought this was one of the defining characteristics of a fiber bundle.

Comment: @mjones - perhaps [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57015/which-principlal-bundles-are-locally-trivial) MO question will help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the $H$ contractible part.

For the general question, have a look at these [notes](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/CHAR/ChapterI.pdf) of Peter May's. Proposition 3.7 states that if $H$ has local cross-sections in $G$ then $p$ will be a principal $H$ bundle. According to Wikipedia this is also in Steenrod's book on fibre bundles. Wiki also has the following

> The most general conditions under which the quotient map will admit local cross-sections are not known, although if $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup (and thus a Lie subgroup by Cartan's theorem), then the quotient map is a fiber bundle. One example of this is the Hopf fibration, $S^3 \to S^2$ which is a fiber bundle over the sphere $S^2$ whose total space is $S^3$. From the perspective of Lie groups, $S^3$ can be identified with the special unitary group $SU(2)$. The abelian subgroup of diagonal matrices is isomorphic to the circle group $U(1)$, and the quotient $SU(2)/U(1)$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere.
>
> More generally, if $G$ is any topological group and $H$ a closed subgroup which also happens to be a Lie group, then G → G/H is a fiber bundle.

There is no reference given for the second part. I suggest having a browse through [Mimura and Toda](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821813420) - it is likely to be in there, although difficult to find.

Comment: thank you for the references!

Comment: Could you please update the link as it is not working now?